# Configuring DNS to access to other server when subdomain

Tags: dns

I have the following DNS entry for my domain example.com:

```
+------+------+-----+------+
| Name | Type | TTL | Data |
+------+------+-----+------+
|  @   |  A   | 1H  | {IP} |
+------+------+-----+------+
```

I have there my rest API, but, now, I want to have also my website there, so in the meantime I am building it and so on, I want to have example.com, and api.example.com pointing to the same IP.

For that I created this:

```
+------+------+-----+------+
| Name | Type | TTL | Data |
+------+------+-----+------+
|  @   |  A   | 1H  | {IP} |
+------+------+-----+------+
| api  |  A   | 1H  | {IP} | (I also tried api.example.com)
+------+------+-----+------+
```

But, after waiting for a while (almost 24h), if I do ping to example.com I get a response, but if I do it to api.example.com, I don't get a response.

what am I doing wrong?

Edit: I'm using Google Domains, and here you have a screenshot[image]:

Regards,

Comment: Can you provide more detail about which DNS server/hosting are you using, maybe even add a screenshot of your entries. (also real domain name would help)

Comment: I edited my comment

Comment: Yep, the way you entered it, `api.mymatchfolio.com.mymatchfolio.com` does reslove to `34.xxx.yyy.34`, so ypu probably need to put only `api` (and `web`) as Name, and then it should work